# Property of interconnected feedback systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control, systems-theory

In the figure you can see the statespace form of a feedback interconnection system.

[image: feedback interconnection]

Very quick question: is there a reason they have taken $D_1=0$ and $D_2=0$?

It makes workings a lot easier but I see no reason as to why this would be true generally.

Comment: Who is "they"? Without context it is hard to say, because there can be different reasons. However, as @Arash said, $D = 0$ is the case in many real world applications, so maybe the authors where just considering systems that represent their actual control problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of practical systems $\boldsymbol D=\boldsymbol 0$.

If you push the gas pedal in your car, does your car jump?

If there is a jump in the temperature, does your thermometer mercury jump immediately?

---

In the real-world, it is rare to find plants and sensors with immediate output. But, sometimes there is a system that approximately gives you an immediate response. What to do with them?

In such cases, for continuous time systems, you can assume that there is a very trivial low-pass filter before or after the block. For discrete systems, you can assume there is a small unit delay before or after the block. The low-pass filter and the delay should be design with minimal impact on the model accuracy and the system needs to be robust enough to tolerate that.

Comment: @smoking_huge_doinks That also depends on the context. Maybe the authors used that representation for a purely theoretical proof of some property of the closed loop system, which however is just valid for the special case that $D = 0$. That could be a valid reason as well, so it doesn't necessarily depend on their investigation being completely theoretically or practically. Both is possible.

Comment: @smoking_huge_doinks, in the most of real systems $\boldsymbol{D}=0$. It is hard to find real control systems with $\boldsymbol{D}\ne0$ when the sample time $T_s$ is small enough. Even with using the most accurate control system, there are a lot of noise and disturbances adding uncertainty to your results. Let's say by adding a lot of complexities you increased the accuracy by 0.1%. How much is the industry interested?